# Tying client side validation parameters to server-side properties?

Tags: javascript, spring, validation

I have a Spring-based site (sepecifically Spring Web Flow) that is completely done, and has extensive and complex **server-side** validation in it.   Now I'm being told to add **client-side** validation to it.

Is there any part of Spring that supports configuring the client-side validation code from the server side, or do I basically have to duplicate all my server-side validation client-side now?   I'm thinking of things like regex patterns and field lengths.   Is there any way to tie code like this from my form backing object:

```
@Size(max=25)
private String contactName;

@Pattern(regexp=Patterns.PHONE, message = "{validation.PHONE}")
private String contactPhone;

@Size(max=50)
private String contactEmail;

@NotNull
private Character approvalRequired;
```

into my Javascript client side validation code?   Or do I have to duplicate all these conditions on the client side?